# Does npm or yarn have feature to automatically install @types if they exist in Typescript projects?

Tags: typescript, npm, yarnpkg

Does `npm` or `yarn` have feature to automatically install `@types/*` for packages without own types, if they exist in Typescript projects?

Something like:

```
//package.json
{
  // ...
  installTypes: true
}

// installing package
yarn add ABC <- will install ABC + @types/ABC
```

Comment: This would be great. Or from the command line, something like `yarn add uuid --ts`

Answer (score 6):

There's a yarn v2+ plugin for this at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript

Since yarn v4, its included by default.

Instructions for installation, when using yarn v2 or v3 is:

```
yarn plugin import typescript
```